# How to do autocomplete telnet of input in java using raw sockets

Tags: java, telnet

I am using a general purpose apache commons library to do the boring networking management so the user can telnet in and start typing in commands to my java command processor. Currently it does not offer stuff like autocomplete of the current token or history which i would like to add.

I know i can watch character by character but i am unsure how to erase and reprint the current line being entered with my new "auto completed line" etc.

Any tips in the general direction would be appreciated.. :)

Answer (score 0):

terminal emulators support *[escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences)*. Those sequences can be used to delete characters on the terminal window and to position the cursor (caret).

Unfortunatly, there are a couple of different standards and your server needs to know the terminal clients standard in order to send the correct control bytes. So either you set a standard for your application, because you always use the same terminal client or you add a command/function to set the standard from your client.

Comment: yes but what are the escape sequences used to rewrite a line, pbviously its home then print again...

Comment: They depend on the *console* that you use. You need to know the *standard* (like VT100 or ANSI), after that you'll find the sequences (I'd use google or wikipedia for a start)

Answer (score 0):

this may be relevant: http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPImmediateDataTransferPushFunction.htm